# QML Popups not working properly with C++ application

Tags: qt, popup, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have an application in Qt in which I can switch between c++ app and QML app (setting central widget to one or other).

The problem is that in order to work this, I had to change my main.qml from ApplicationWindow to Page and now Dialogs and all Popups in my QML app are not working properly (modality and focus is not working at all).

My code looks like that:

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget(this);
view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));  //Page

MyCppApp *myCppApp = new MyCppApp (this);  //QWidget

QStackedWidget *stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
stackedWidget->addWidget(view);
stackedWidget->addWidget(myCppApp);
stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);

setCentralWidget(stackedWidget);
```

I know in Popup's documentation there is that "It can be used with Window or ApplicationWindow." but is there a way to get Popups in my QML work properly?

I am using Qt 5.8 and Qt Quick Controls 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the modality you should not make the dialog window part of central widget in main window (otherwise it is modal relative to what?). Invoke it from main window. And to give it modal dialog looks and behavior you can apply window flags like that:

```
// this view is not a part of the app main window
view->setFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::WindowTitleHint |
                     Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint  | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

Mind that `Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint` is of course applicable on Windows only. And for setting the focus:

```
// to set the edit focus such trick needed
QTimer::singleShot(0, view, SLOT(setFocus()));
```

I use that with QML widget container. Implementation details may differ. And no QML part visible. There you may need to take care of [FocusScope](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-focusscope.html) then.